# Distance from UITableView Cells and Current Location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am creating an iOS application where I have some data structure containing multiple coordinates and I know the current user location. I want to fill the cells of the TableView with the distance from the user's current location to the locations in the TableView.

I was wondering when I should calculate the distance between the user's current location and all the locations in the TableView. Should I calculate **all** these distances when the application starts? What should I do when the user changes location? Set some sort of timer to check if the user's position changed and recalculate the distances every time the user's position changed?

I should also note, I am giving them the ability to sort this TableView by distance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's the problem ?

Comment: I was asking if I should calculate all the distances from the current location  to all locations in the table view when the app begins or upon viewing a particular location in the table view? And when should I update these distances as the user travels?

Answer (score 0):

You can user CLLocationManagerDelegate's locationManager:didUpdateLocations: Method.

This method is called when user's location will update so you can call your method to show data in tableview from user's current location.

below is some code for sorting your arryOfLocation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrySortByLocation.count; i++)
    {
        //Current Location Details
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[arrySortByLocation objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];

        CLLocationDegrees latitude = [dict[@"city_lat"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longitude = [dict[@"city_lng"] doubleValue];
        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
        CLLocationDistance distance = [appDele.userLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
        dict[@"distance"] = [@(distance) stringValue];

        //Storing as string since latitude and longitude is also string values
        //Since its a dictionary storing as NSNumber is better

        [arrySearchLocation setObject:dict atIndexedSubscript:i];
    }

    //sorting based on distance
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance.doubleValue" ascending:YES];
    [arrySortByLocation sortUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
}
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Thank you for the insight. So I should recalculate the distance when the user's position changes and sort again? Is there a way to check that they are some distance from their last location before recalculating and sorting?

Comment: You can use CLLocationManagerDelegate's locationManager:didUpdateLocations: Method where you can do what ever you want before recalculate sorting.